# Monitoring the state of a MediaPlayer in the GUI

Tags: android

Android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) describes how `MediaPlayer` changes state as outlined in this diagram:

[image: MediaPlayer states]

I'd like to update my GUI to provide the user with playback feedback. There should be a label in the interface that says "Playing", "Buffering" or "Stopped" depending on the state of the player. How can I implement this? I've been looking for something like an `OnStateChangedListener`, but apparently that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For buffering you can listen `setOnBufferingUpdateListener`.
For "Playing" and "Stopped" after `onPrepared`() is called, you can monitor getCurrentPosition.